# Finding index where string 2 starts in the righmost area of string 2

Tags: java, string

I am writing a program with multiple methods, and one of them asks to find the index where the second strings starts in the rightmost area of the first string.

The method accepts two strings as parameters and returns the character index of the position where the second string begins in the rightmost area of the first.

For example:

> IN: mississippi, ss
>
> OUT: 5

The catch of this method is that I can only use `charAt`, `substring` and `length` from the `String` class, and no other class methods.

With the help of some users from this site, we came up with this:

```
public static int findInStr1(String s1, String s2) {
  for (int i = 0; i < s1.length() - s2.length(); i++) {
    boolean found = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < s2.length(); j++) {
       if (s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(j)) {
          found = false;
          break;
       }
    }
    if (found) {
        return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;  
}
```

The above method gives me the index where string 2 starts in string 1, but I am trying to code a method that gives me the index of where string 2 starts in the rightmost area of string 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust your method to scan the first String from the right to the left :

```
public static int findInStr1(String s1, String s2) {
  for (int i = s1.length() - 1; i >= s2.length() - 1; i--) {
    boolean found = true;
    for (int j = s2.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
       if (s1.charAt(i-(s2.length()-1-j)) != s2.charAt(j)) {
          found = false;
          break;
       }
    }
    if (found) {
        return i-s2.length()+1;
    }
  }
  return -1;  
}
```